# Paste/Collapse in R

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I'm confused by paste, and thought it was just simple concatenating.

```
whales <- c("C","D","C","D","D")

quails <- c("D","D","D","D","D")

results <-paste(whales, quails, collapse = '')
```

Why would this return "C DD DC DD DD D" instead of CD DD CD DD DD?

Moreover, why would

```
results <-paste(whales[1], quails[1], collapse = '')
```

return

"C D" ?

with a space?

Thanks,
D

EDIT

OK, I see that

```
results <-paste(whales, quails, collapse = NULL, sep='')
```

will get me what I want, but an explanation of why the previous code didn't work? And also thank you to the answerers.

Comment: Why down votes? It is a legitimate question and also well-framed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the first question, try the following (which might be more illustrative than choosing to repeat 2 characters).

```
### Note that R paste's together corresponding elements together...
paste(c("A", "S", "D", "F"), 
      c("W", "X", "Y", "Z"))

[1] "A W" "S X" "D Y" "F Z"

### Note that with collapse, R converts the above 
  # result into a length 1 character vector.
paste(c("A", "S", "D", "F"), 
      c("W", "X", "Y", "Z"), collapse = '')

[1] "A WS XD YF Z"
```

What you really want to do (to get the "desired" result) is the following:

```
### "Desired" result:
paste(whales, quails, sep = '', collapse = ' ')

[1] "CD DD CD DD DD"
```

Note that we are specifying the `sep` and `collapse` arguments to different values, which relates to your second question. `sep` allows each terms to be separated by a character string, whereas `collapse` allows the entire result to be separated by a character string.

Try

```
paste(whales, quails, collapse = '', sep = '')

[1] "CDDDCDDDDD"
```

Alternatively, use a shortcut `paste0`, which defaults to `paste` with `sep = ''`

```
paste0(whales, quails, collapse = '')
```

Comment: I still don't find tthe answer of WHY the result of paste(c("A", "S", "D", "F"), 
      c("W", "X", "Y", "Z"), collapse = '') is like that. During my hit n trials, I too got the answer that for desired output, we need either the sep = "" or use paste0(). but still I couldn't understand the behavior of above-mentioned code.

Answer (score 63):

For those who like visuals, here is my take at explaining how `paste` works in `R`:

[image]

`sep` creates element-wise sandwich stuffed with the value in the `sep` argument:

[image]

`collapse` creates ONE big sandwich with the value of `collapse` argument added between the sandwiches produced by using the `sep` argument:

[image]

Comment: Nice visuals for a simple concept, did you create those in R? How?

Comment: @DrNishaArora, I created the illustrations using PowerPoint.

Comment: Yeah, we can make wonderful images n animation in PowerPoint. I got curious about making that in R.

Comment: @DrNishaArora, there might be a way, but I am not familiar with how we can do that!