# Passing Along Column Values to Paste

Tags: r, naming, paste

This is a follow-up to [Paste/Collapse in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475202/paste-collapse-in-r)
I assume its preferable to start a new question than to endlessly edit a previous question with new questions.

What I've got going on is some vectors that I want to simulate playing a game against. The goal is to randomly pick two strategies to play against each other, where afterwards the results matrix is made, a magical for loop will assign each strategy a score.

```
###Sample Strategies
whales <- c("C","D","C","D","D")
quails <- c("D","D","D","D","D")
snails <- c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
bales  <- c("D", "D", "C", "D", "C")

####Combining into a matrix
gameboard<-cbind(whales, quails, bales, snails, deparse.level = 1)

####All of the names of the strategies/columns
colnames(gameboard)

####Randomly pick two random column names
game1<- colnames(gameboard)[sample(1:ncol(gameboard), 2, replace= FALSE)]

results <-paste(game1[1], game1[2], sep='')
```

Now this does work, except for I am actually accessing the column names, not the data in the columns. So I end up with results like 'whalesbales' when I want the actual concatenation of CD DD CC DD DC.

Maybe 'apply' or 'lapply'...apply here?

The inevitable follow up question is how can I get the last line where it says 'results' to instead say 'results_whalesVbales'?
because I assume

```
results"game1[1]", sep='V',game1[2]"
```

is not going to cut it, and there is some ugly way to do this with lots of parentheses and block quotes.

#

FOLLOW UP

Thanks in advance for advice.

Thanks Ferdinand for the response and thorough explanation- 
A couple of follow ups:

(1) Is there a way to get the
    paste(.Last.value, collapse=" ")
    [1] "DC DD CC DD CD"

result to be a new object (vector?) that is named result_balesVwhales based on

```
 paste0("results_", paste(colnames(gameboard [randompair],collapse="V"))
 [1] "results_balesVwhales"
```

everything I've tried so far makes the vector have a value of results_balesVwhales.

(2) Can I force the new results_balesVwhales to have the "long" (columnar) format that bales and whales each have individually, w/o reshape?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being dense, but does: `paste(gameboard[, game1[1]], gameboard[, game1[2]], sep='', collapse=' ')` Do what you're looking for?  You can also just `sample(colnames(gameboard), 2)` directly and save some steps and letters.

Comment: no you're not being dense- I was just being too clever(too dumb) by half. I was worried that R would try and pick from more columns than there were, and that it could pick the same column twice, both things I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I've removed my answer since you believe it's not what you wanted.

Comment: Hi @Ferdinand.kraft, if it is possible, please un delete your answer as it was precisely what I wanted. It was moreover very constructive and instructional. I unchecked the answer to hopefully have alerted you to the follow up.
I really appreciate your earlier answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ferdinand has the first question answered.  In regards to your second questions...  the function you are asking about is `assign`.

```
 x = 'foo'
 assign(x, 2)
 foo
 # [1] 2
```

However, there be dragons...  Instead, the R way of doing that would be to assign into an element of a named list:

```
game1 <- sample(colnames(gameboard), 2)
result <- list()
list_name <- paste0("results_", paste(colnames(gameboard)[game1], collapse="V"))
result[[list_name]] <- paste(gameboard[, game1[1]], 
                             gameboard[, game1[2]], 
                             sep='', 
                             collapse=' ')
```

If you want the vector of pasted elements, just remove the `collapse` as I've done below.

Eventually, once I sorted out how I wanted this all to work, I would wrap it in a function or two.  These can be much cleaner, but the verbosity illustrates the idea.

```
my_game <- function(trial, n_samples, dat) {
    # as per my comment, generate the game result and name using the colnames directly
    game <- sample(colnames(dat), n_samples)
    list_name <- paste0("results_", paste(game, collapse="V"))
    game_result <- paste(dat[, game[1]], 
                         dat[, game[2]], 
                         sep='')

    # return both the name and the data in the format desired to parse out later
    return(list(list_name, game_result))
}

my_game_wrapper <- function(trials, n_samples, dat) {
   # for multiple trials we create a list of lists of the results and desired names
   results <- lapply(1:trials, my_game, n_samples, dat)
   # extract the names and data
   result_names <- sapply(results, '[', 1)
   result_values <- sapply(results, '[', 2)

   # and return them once the list is pretty.
   names(result_values) <- result_names
   return(result_values)
}

my_game_wrapper(3, 2, gameboard)

# $results_quailsVwhales
# [1] "DC" "DD" "DC" "DD" "DD"

# $results_quailsVbales
# [1] "DD" "DD" "DC" "DD" "DC"

# $results_balesVquails
# [1] "DD" "DD" "CD" "DD" "CD"
```